# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' の対処方法

Tags: python, pandas

以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "　", line 7, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(u'日経平均_2014.csv', encoding='shift-jis')
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

以下コードになります。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# [[短期, 長期], [短期, 長期] ・・・]
types = [[5, 25], [25, 75], [13, 26]]

df = pd.read_csv(u'日経平均_2014.csv', encoding='shift-jis')
df = df.sort_values(by=u'日付').reset_index(drop=True)

for short_day, long_day in types:

    # 移動平均
    rolling_s  = df[u'終値'].rolling(short_day).mean().fillna(0)
    rolling_l  = df[u'終値'].rolling(long_day).mean().fillna(0)

    # 移動平均のクロス確認
    over_s_l  = rolling_s  > rolling_l
    golden = (over_s_l != over_s_l.shift(1)) & (over_s_l == True)
    dead   = (over_s_l != over_s_l.shift(1)) & (over_s_l == False)

    # 列 追加
    #   0：クロスなし
    #   1：ゴールデンクロス
    #  -1：デッドクロス
    col_name = 'cross_' + str(short_day) + '_' + str(long_day)
    df[col_name] = [x+y*-1 for x,y in zip(golden, dead)]
    df[col_name] = np.append(np.array([0] * (long_day+1)), df[col_name][long_day+1:])
    #
```

Comment: Python インタプリタで `import pandas as pd` した後 `print(pd.__version__)` するとどう出力されますか？ ([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20612645/5989200))

Answer (score 2):

カレントディレクトリに`pandas.py`があってそれを読み込んでしまっているように思います。