# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
INP_FILE='data.csv'
DATA = pd.read_csv(INP_FILE,engine='python')
```

を実行すると題名の通り

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

となります。
アドバイスよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参考: [AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' の対処方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37366/)

Comment: 参考リンク先にもありますが競合してる可能性が高いです。例えばこの質問中のコードを保存している`py`ファイルの名前は何でしょうか？

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。ファイル名を直したところread_csvが_libsという別のエラーに変わってしまいました。